# replace character ` doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, php-5.2

I have a webform where you can upload files. To replace special characters I user the following function:

```
function createSafeFilenameForQuestion($filename){
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "_",  $filename);
    $search  = array("ä", "ö", "ü", "ß", "Ö", "Ä", "Ü");
    $replace = array("ae","oe","ue","ss","Oe","Ae","Ue");
    $ret = str_replace($search, $replace, $filename);
    $in_charset = mb_detect_encoding($filename);
    $ret = iconv($in_charset, 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/\s/i", "_", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z_\.]/i", "", $ret);
    $filename = mb_strtolower($ret);
    return $filename;
}
createSafeFilenameForQuestion("ä#`´+4`32 _.png");
```

My problem is, that this code works fine on my local machine with PHP 5.2.5 and it doesn't work on the server with PHP 5.2.0.

```
local output: aeae432__.png
server output: ae
```

It seems, that the character `´` is the problem.

Comment: Does the server have the mbstring extensions installed?

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` doesn't do what you think. In fact is basically useless. Also, doing both `iconv($in_charset, 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ret);` and manual replacements is redundant. /// In any case, my tip is to not care at all about the original name of the file. Assign one yourself, possibly a random one, and use the original name just on download headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mbstring` was installed and enabled. But as Álvarao said, using `iconv($in_charset, 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ret);` wasn't necessary. I removed the line and now it works.

```
function createSafeFilenameForQuestion($filename){
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "_",  $filename);

    $search  = array("ä", "ö", "ü", "ß", "Ö", "Ä", "Ü");
    $replace = array("ae","oe","ue","ss","Oe","Ae","Ue");
    $ret = str_replace($search, $replace, $filename);

    $ret = preg_replace("/\s/i", "_", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z_\.]/i", "", $ret);
    $filename = mb_strtolower($ret);
    return $filename;
}
```

Input: ää#`´+4`32 _.png
Output: ae432__.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `mbstring` extension installed on your server, to check you can create a php file with `phpinfo();` and then run it to see whether `mbstring` is installed/loaded or not.

if it is not installed you can install it by running followinng command:

`apt-get install php5-mbstring`

`service apache2 restart`

and to enable it run:

`sudo phpenmod mbstring`

this should fix the issue.

but if you are on shared hosting server then you will need to contact hosting support to enable it...